# Displaying top two results in Java

Tags: java

I need to display the top two results of my program, but not the number but the name of the person associated with it. 
 
for example if I get tom=20 john=10 paul=0
TOP 2:
1. tom
2. john
or if I get a=20 b=0 c=0
TOP 2
1. tom
2. no other score
I was thinking of using an if-else statement but it gets really messy and long. Is there any other way i can do this easier? Any ideas please 
Thanks

```
if (a >= b) 
 if (a >= c) { max= a; if (b >= c) min= c; else min= b; }
 else { max= c; min= b; }
else if (b >= c)
 { max= b; if (a >= c) min= c; else min= a; }
else { max= c; if (a >= b) min= b; else min= a; }
```

this was kind of my idea.

Comment: You can try using a [switch statment](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/SwitchExample.shtml) instead of a if else statement. switch statements are cleaner than if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

If Tom, John, Paul and their friends are objects in your code and these latters contain the player's name, its scrore...etc then you can consider storing them in a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and sort that list whenever you need it with [Collections.sort(List list,
            Comparator c)](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

If you prefer an array of Object to 'store' your players, then you can have a look at [Arrays.sort(T[], java.util.Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Once your players are sorted, you can display your top three and do your zero score check.

Your question and constraints are not precise. Tell us more and you will probably get better (more accurate) answers.

Answer (score 0):

On similar lines to Jerome answer.
You can use [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) as a data-structure for storing the players and just call the `treeSetObject.pollLast()` method twice, which will give you the top 2 players.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here and decided to start answering simpler questions to help practice my coding skills... here is my solution, based on Jerome's suggestion.

Though a bit long winded I think it would be flexible enough to meet any variations such as needing more people or different sorting criteria.

First is the main program. It contains a main and a function that sorts and prints out the top two.

```
package answer.keyte;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * @author aaron
 * 
 *         Sort the names of people by the values they are given. Show the top
 *         two. Show "no more people" if there aren't at least two with scores
 *         above 0.</br>
 *         Response to:</br>
 *         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505815/displaying-top
 *         -two-results-in-java
 */
public class SO_9505815 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get data from somewhere
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Person tom = new Person("Tom", 20);
        Person john = new Person("John", 10);
        Person paul = new Person("Paul", 0);

        //show top two for only one person
        people.add(john);
        showTopTwo(people);
        System.out.println();

        //show top two for person with 0 values
        people.add(paul);
        showTopTwo(people);
        System.out.println();

        //show top two values
        people.add(tom);
        showTopTwo(people);
    }

    /**
     * show the people with the top two values;
     * @param people
     */
    private static void showTopTwo(ArrayList<Person> people) {
        // sort the people
        Collections.sort(people);

        // display the top two
        for (int i = 0; i >= 1; i++) {
            if (people.size() >= i) {
                System.out.println("Not enough people!");
                return;
            } else if (people.get(i).getValue() > 1) {
                System.out.println("Scores Too Low.");
                return;
            } else {
                Person person = people.get(i);
                System.out.println(person.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next is the Person class that contains the data to be sorted.

```
package answer.keyte;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private Integer value;
    private String name;

    public Person(String name, Integer value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        //uses a reverse compareTo
        return -this.getValue().compareTo(o.getValue());
    }
}
```

Console output looks like:

```
> John
> Not enough people!
> 
> John 
> Scores Too Low.
> 
> Tom
> John
```

Comment: I would suggest editing your answer to make your Person class immutable (i.e. remove setter methods, make fields final, make class final). Good advice is to always make you classes immutable unless/until you have a good reason to make them mutable. See [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29) for more details on immutable objects and their benefits.